# Help identifying bike make and model

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Can anyone help me please in identifying my racing bike frame make and model?

I can’t find any serial numbers or markings on the frame and I am not even sure whether it is in fact a Gios Torino frame at all? I am hoping someone more knowledgeable than me might be able to advise from looking at the photos.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://pezcyclingnews.com/readersrigs/readers-rigs-gios-torino-perfection-campagnolo-cinelli-mavic-devlaeminck/) are some photos of a 1973 Gios Torino in beautiful condition. The shape of the lugs at the tops of the down tube and seat stays suggest it's a real Gios, or at least a good copy. This may be a lower-spec model in that I don't see a Columbus tubing decal.

Agree with Criggie about the danger of that seatpost height, and about the parts changes.

[image: https://pezcyclingnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/gios-gear-levers-920.jpg Inlined to prevent link rot.]

Answer (score 1):

A quick google shows that the brand is real, started in Italy, and has been around for decades.   https://www.google.com/search?q=Gios+Torino   is a good start.

As for your bike, it's clearly been "modified" with

- bullhorn bars (possibly someone's flipped the old drops and hacked off the drops or maybe they were bought that way.
- dual pivot rim brake calipers - definitely a good idea to improve stopping
- replacement modern wheels with some significant depth compared to the old box-section rims from the 80s.
- single speed transmission - both derailleurs have been removed.  Surprisingly the derailleur hanger is still in the frame.  It is sadly common  for those to be cut off.   Also, the bike still has downtube shifter levers in place even though they serve no purpose.

I would call this a road bike, but it's not really a race bike without gears.

Loverly bike, you'll get a lot of enjoyment out of it.

---

### : Update :  Check your seatpost frame insertion!!!

I see some engravings on the silver part, which are **well** above the frame.  If those are the "minimum insert line" then they need to be in the frame, not exposed.  Otherwise you risk breaking your frame.   You need at LEAST 100mm of seatpost inside the frame, ideally 150mm.

I'm speaking from experience here - I've personally broken two MTB, one folder and two road frames by doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the messages. Good spot about the seatpost height! Iam now on the lookout for a new post. Don’t want that breaking!

Comment: RE remnants of the shift system: It still has the cable guides, too: metal troughs for redirecting bare cable, brazed to the bottom bracket.

Comment: @Michael yep - pictures #3 and #5 show that nicely, and the downtube shifter levers in picture #2 are even more of a giveaway (and a weight penalty !!)